# Angular home route on ionic doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my first app on ionic and angular too,the home route doesnt work
,the view is not loaded but the other views are shown.
I'm not sure about the route because  is http://localhost:8101/#/ innstead of http://localhost:8101/

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var starter = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);

starter.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

starter.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
    controller : 'mainController'
  })
  .state('acerca',{
    url: '/acerca',
    templateUrl : 'pages/acerca.html',
    controller : 'aboutController'
  })
  .state('contacto',{
    url: '/contacto',
    templateUrl : 'pages/contacto.html',
    controller : 'contactController'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});

starter.controller('mainController',function($scope){
  $scope.message = 'Hola,mundo';
});

starter.controller('aboutController',function($scope){
  $scope.message = 'Acerca de';
});

starter.controller('contactController',function($scope){
  $scope.message = 'Contacto';
});
```

the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-route.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

and a view

```
<ion-view> 
    <ion-content> 
      <h1>Home</h1> 
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
      <a href = "#/home">Home</a>
      <a href = "#/acerca">Acerca</a>
      <a href = "#/contacto">Contacto</a>
   <ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Now the view content are not shown.

Comment: Ionic does provide `ui,router` routing engine out of the box.. why do you need `ngRouter` there?

Comment: I didn't know it ,its the first time I use ionic ,thank you

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to use `$stateProvider` and `$urlRouterProvider` instead of `$routeProvider` from ngRouter as below:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var starter = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);

starter.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

starter.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl : 'home.html',
    controller : 'mainController'
  })
  .state('acerca',{
    url: '/acerca',
    templateUrl : 'pages/acerca.html',
    controller : 'aboutController'
  })
  .state('contacto',{
    url: '/contacto',
    templateUrl : 'pages/contacto.html',
    controller : 'contactController'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});

starter.controller('mainController',function($scope){
  $scope.message = 'Hola,mundo';
});

starter.controller('aboutController',function($scope){
  $scope.message = 'Acerca de';
});

starter.controller('contactController',function($scope){
  $scope.message = 'Contacto';
});
```

Also, the probable issue in your existing code was that you had a typo in your `otherwise()` method wherein you were using `redirecTo` instead of `redirectTo`

Comment: Not sure, how ngRouter will work with ionic.. Though +1 for ui.router implementation & typo catches

Comment: It won't be able to leverage the states, navigation directives etc. but the url routing will work as it is just a routing mechanism on an angular (ionic being built on top of angular) app. What do you think? I haven't tried but I think it should work. Will give it a try and will let you know

Comment: I've edited de original post, now the view content is not shown.